# Erasing boot failed,device may be locked

Tags: fastboot, rom, mi-a1

I am flashing fastboot ROM in my mi A1 using mi flash tools but at the time of flashing it is showing the error:erasing boot failed device may be locked and I am not able to flash the ROM.Why is this happening?

Comment: This may be happening because the bootloader is locked. This prevents writing/modifying data in sensitive areas such as boot partition. Unlock it first

Comment: If i unlock the bootloader manually then it shows some 'corruption' error and phone keeps on rebooting unless I lock it back.

Comment: What do you mean? Is it possible to show us the error message